# How to target $(this) in anime.js

Tags: anime.js

I am trying to achieve a click animation on a `<a>` tag. There are multiple `<a>` tags and all of them have the same class.

How do I achieve this?

As an alternative, i had tried adding a class as temporary to the targetted `element using $(this).addClass('temp')`

I need to know if there is a better way to actually do it .

If i go with the above method, i wont be able to bring animations with delays .

sample1

sample2

```
<script>
$(a).click(function(){
anime({
targets:'a',
opacity:[0,1],
})
});
```